# Jetpack Compose focus requester not working with Dialog

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using the below code to try and request focus to a textfield and have the keyboard come up. Currently the textfield does request focus but the keyboard fails to show. This same code works in another project im working on, but the difference here is this code is inside a Dialog composable, and the other code isn't, so I'm not sure if its the Dialog making the keyboard fail to show?

```
val textField = remember { FocusRequester() }

 Dialog(onDismissRequest = {
    openDialog.value = false
    dialogInput.value = ""
}) {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(274.dp)
            .background(Color.Transparent)
            .clickable {
                openDialog.value = false
                dialogInput.value = ""
            }
    ) {

        OutlinedTextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(64.dp)
                .background(Color.White)
                .focusRequester(textField),
            label = {
                Text(
                    text = label,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2.copy(color = Color.Black)
                )
            },
            value = dialogInput.value,
            onValueChange = {
                dialogInput.value = it
                events.filterPlayers(it)
            },
            textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.body2.copy(color = Color.Black),
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                backgroundColor = Color.White,
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.White,
                focusedIndicatorColor = Color.White
            )
        )

        DisposableEffect(Unit) {
            textField.requestFocus()
            onDispose {}
        }
}
```

Comment: I'm using `LaunchedEffect(Unit)` and ran into the same issue. Adding a small delay (200 ms) seems to work fine before doing `.requestFocus()` seems to make it work. Hacky, but it's something.

Comment: Instead of `delay(200)`, you can also use `awaitFrame()` in `LaunchedEffect`.

Comment: I've had to use two `awaitFrame()` in `LaunchedEffect`. One works but not every time, but two works every time from my testing

Comment: @C.Allan and JacobRas, these are great answers. You should post them in the answers section.

Answer (score 6):

```
val focusRequester = FocusRequester()
LocalView.current.viewTreeObserver.addOnWindowFocusChangeListener {
    if (it) focusRequester.requestFocus()
}
```

this work for me, after window for dialog get focused, request focus for TextField would show soft keyboard automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's safer to use `remember { FocusRequester() }`. Also here's a [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/204502668) to this issue on Compose issue tracker, you can add it to your answer too.

Answer (score 1):

A more robust solution from https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/204502668 is the following which uses the `LaunchedEffect` side effect instead of just adding a listener in every recomposition:

```kotlin
val windowInfo = LocalWindowInfo.current

LaunchedEffect(windowInfo) {
    snapshotFlow { windowInfo.isWindowFocused }.collect { isWindowFocused ->
        if (isWindowFocused) {
            focusRequester.requestFocus()
        }
    }
}
```