# How to show keyboard with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-windowmanager, android-window

How can I slide in the keyboard?
I tried:

```
val keyboardController: SoftwareKeyboardController? = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
  keyboardController?.show()
```

But it does not work. What am I missing? Maybe some Manifest flags?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To show keyboard in Compose:

```kotlin
val showKeyboard = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
val keyboard = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current

OutlinedTextField(
    modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .focusRequester(focusRequester),
    value = value,
    textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.body2,
    onValueChange = { onValueChange(it)},
    label = { Text(label) }
)

// LaunchedEffect prevents endless focus request
LaunchedEffect(focusRequester) {
    if (showKeyboard.equals(true)) {
        focusRequester.requestFocus()
        delay(100) // Make sure you have delay here
        keyboard?.show()
    }
}
```

Comment: This code does not work when you open a dialog and want the textfield in dialog to be auto focused and keyboard slide open. The textfield focuses, but the keyboard doesn't slide open.

Comment: @ino See here for dialogs. Just move the delay before the `requestFocus()`, or use `awaitFrame()`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69750447/jetpack-compose-focus-requester-not-working-with-dialog

Comment: showKeyboard.equals(true) always returns false here because equals() Indicates whether one other object is "equal to" the other one not if they have the same value. See examples here - https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-objectsequals-in-java , instead just use if(showKeyboard.value)

Comment: should be:   
if (showKeyboard.value) {...

Comment: Anyway the code never sets showKeyboard.value to false. So why is the variable there?

Comment: Never anywhere rely on delay. `awaitFrame()` is enough

Answer (score 16):

`delay` is not a robust way to show a keyboard. Keyboard is not shown because the window is not focused yet in most cases. The solution would be like this:

```
val windowInfo = LocalWindowInfo.current
val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
TextField(modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester)...)

LaunchedEffect(windowInfo) {
     snapshotFlow { windowInfo.isWindowFocused }.collect { isWindowFocused ->
         if (isWindowFocused) {
             focusRequester.requestFocus()
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't we use request focus as a side effect?

Comment: Tried the `awaitFrame` and it seems to reduce the error rate of failed kbd hidings to something around 10%. But with your approach I can't get even a single failure! I guess `awaitFrame` sometimes is too short period for the window to become in focus. I wonder do we really need `snapshotFlow`? Can't we just access `isWindowFocused` directly?

Answer (score 7):

I am currently using the compose BOM version `2023.05.01`.

The other answers did not work for me. However, I did manage to get it to work when I changed the LaunchedEffect from the accepted answer. With the following code snippet, the software keyboard opens and you can start typing inside of the textfield.

```
val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }

OutlinedTextField(
    modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .focusRequester(focusRequester),
    value = value,
    textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.body2,
    onValueChange = { onValueChange(it)},
    label = { Text(label) }
)

LaunchedEffect(focusRequester) {
   awaitFrame()
   focusRequester.requestFocus()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For my use case, I needed the keyboard to be shown when there is a bottom sheet shown with the editText. The accepted answer works for the first time and then stops working if the user switches to a different app for some time (interruptions). So I combined the above solution with a lifecycle event to trigger the keyboard when the view is actually visible to the user.

```kotlin
fun SomeView(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current) {
 val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
 val keyboard = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
 val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()


 DisposableEffect(key1 = lifecycleOwner, effect = {

       val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->

           scope.launch {
               if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME) {
                   focusRequester.requestFocus()
                   awaitFrame()
                   keyboard?.show()
               }
           }
       }

       // Add the observer to the lifecycle
       lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)

       onDispose {
           lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
       }
   })


         TextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .focusRequester(focusRequester),
            value = "",
            onValueChange = {},
            placeholder = { Text(text = "New Note") },
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
            )
        )
```

The above adds a lifecycle observer and triggers the Keyboard show when the lifecycle event is `ON_RESUME`.

Answer (score 1):

The following works fine when it is needed to show keyboard for an edit when scene is opened:

```
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) { focusRequester.requestFocus() }

    TextField(
        ...
        modifier = Modifier
           .fillMaxWidth()
           .focusRequester(focusRequester),
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer from Leon Wu https://stackoverflow.com/a/75985103/4908512 seems to be the best one. For my use case, it was better to put request focus in a side effect.

```
val focusRequester = remember {
    FocusRequester()
}
var queryText by remember(query) { mutableStateOf(query) }

val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
val windowInfo = LocalWindowInfo.current

SideEffect {
    scope.launch {
        snapshotFlow { windowInfo.isWindowFocused }.collect { isWindowFocused ->
            if (isWindowFocused && requestFocus) {
                focusRequester.requestFocus()
            }
        }
    }
}
TextField(modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester)...)
```

Comment: Your answer does not compile.

Comment: @J.Doe The same code compiles for me.

Comment: Nonsense, you are referring to a variable `query` which isn't defined anywhere

Comment: The answer is not on how to use query. Its on how to show the keyboard. This is just code snippet not the whole code.

Comment: Useless, whats the point adding unrelated non-compiling code snippets? It makes no sense

Answer (score -10):

What's the issue with the official method?

```
fun showSoftKeyboard(view: View) {
    if (view.requestFocus()) {
        val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
    }
}
```

Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input).

This method works if you just use it like this:

```
showSoftKeyboard(AndroidView(context))
```

You could also try eliminating the parameter entirely by placing the `AndroidView` in the function's body instead.

Comment: This worked, but since I work with Jetpack Compose only, I don't like the view in the show-Method.

Comment: That's nothing, just pass an AndroidView Composable to it and it'll do. You can just create an empty AndroidView for the purpose. This seems really simplistic so i find it ideal.

Comment: Do not include meta-commentary in your answer. This is not the place for it. If you want to ask what is wrong with this approach, ask a new question. If you want to know how to improve this question, you can ask on Meta. Asking your readers what's wrong is not appropriate.